How to prove crossing number is 3?
Find the crossing number of the following graph
I find that there are 3 edge crossings in the given graph. So I can conclude that the crossing number is less than or equal to 3. However, I am confused how to prove that  the crossing number equals 3.
I tried this:
If crossing number<3, then deletion of two edges will result in a planar graph. In the given graph we have 7 vertices and 17 edges.
Thus if we remove 2 edges, we have 15 edges. Also a planar graph satisfies $e\le 3n-6$.
Hence $15\le 3(7)-6=15$ which is true.
Any hints on how to proceed with the given problem. Kindly help me

Find all complete subgraphs on the four vertices. Use the fact that the complete graph $K_4$ divides the plane into $4$ triangles (if its edges do not intersect) and if a vertex lies inside one of the triangles, then one of the edges connecting this vertex and one of the vertices of $K_4$ necessarily gives an crossing.

@kabenyuk; I am unable to understand your arguments. Is it possible to elaborate it a bit?

I will try to briefly describe my solution.

Let our graph G be somehow drawn in the plane. The graph $G$ contains two subgraphs with vertices $23157$ and $34157$ isomorphic to $K_5$ and a subgraph $H$ with vertices $246157$ isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ (after removing the extra edges).

The crossing number of the subgraph $G-6$ is $2$ (why?).

In view of 1, the graph $G-6$ contains two subgraphs isomorphic to $K_5$ and none of them has vertices $2$ and $4$ at the same time.

By 2 and 3, every pair of crossing edges of $G-6$ has an edge with two odd vertices.

However, the subgraph $H$ also has a pair of crossing edges, and each edge of it has exactly one even vertex. Therefore, a crossing of these edges is different from the two crossings found earlier.


It follows that the crossing number of $G$ is $3$.

I don't understand the "contradiction" part. This is a contradiction to which statement.

@Olivia I simplified the logic of reasoning and edited my answer.

@licheng Thanks for noticing and correcting my silly typo.

In point number $3$, won't it be $K_5$ instead of $K_4$?

Olivia, I think you're right. I rephrased point 3. You ask very good questions.

Aww, thank you Sir. You helped me a lot! Love you
